# Disable item selection in combobox on up and down arrows

Tags: c#, winforms

can anybody suggest how to disable selecting items in combo box on up and down arrows.

I have tried setting event's handling to true on key up and down but it was completely disabling navigating through items on up and down keys.

thanks,

Comment: are you asking in windows form?

Comment: Sorry.... Missed that. Yes, in winforms.

Comment: do you want to just `Focus` the elements while navigating in combobox rows and not select them?

Comment: Well I don't know how to do it :/

Comment: The item displayed in the control is the selected item.  You can't display an item without selecting it.

Comment: Could you post your original problem (aka *what you are trying to achieve*)?

Comment: You could save your current selected value on `KeyDown` (with `Keys.Up` or `Keys.Down`) and then reset `ComboBox.Text` to that on `KeyUp`.

Comment: You are disabling the use of the keyboard? I don't recommend that. Users forced to use inaccessible applications often arm themselves with pitchforks. It's hard to think of a legitimate reason why keyboard navigation needs to be disabled.

Comment: @CodyGray, I don't want to disable the use of KeyBoard. I would like to navigate through list of items on KeyUp and KeyDown but I don't want item to be selected on KeyUp and KeyDown.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,

```
  this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (cbSender, cbe) =>
            {
                var cb = cbSender as ComboBox;
                cb.SelectedIndex = -1;

            };
```

Comment: _I have tried setting event's handling to true on key up and down but it was completely disabling navigating through items on up and down keys._

Comment: @Bolu Modified the answer